# Why won't my Minecraft custom skin change?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

It's been almost 10 years since 1.6.4 has been released and today I am having a issue with this version. My skin is registered with minecraft.net already, but my skin is not showing up.

I tried char.png method but still didn't work, is there any fix?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Duplicate of what? If you know this question was already asked, then please don't ask it again.

Comment: I'm just asking for help.

Comment: @DeklDell-45 If this is a duplicate of a question, the question will be deleted. Other than that, is there any more info you can give us?

Comment: @DeklDell-45 We're not mad, we're just looking to keep things organized, as we're a knowledge base, not a forum.

Answer (score 3):

You're running into this [bug](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/WEB-985):

Skins are now supported only in Minecraft 1.7.9 (released in April 2014) and newer versions, because older versions relied on an API that has since been deprecated and removed. You may have luck working around this with mods such as [Skin fixer](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/skin-fixer) or [Lumy Skin patch](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/lumy-skin-patch).